# Line detection on CUDA

Tags: cuda, hough-transform

I am trying to do real time line detection using CUDA. I have calculated the hough transform along with the min, max line coordinates of each bin. For getting the line segments I am tracing (using Bresenham's line algorithm) through the min to max point and get the line segments on each bin. When the hough threshold is low and when lot of lines are there in the image trace_lines takes lot of time to complete.

hough transform (hough_line_transform) computation takes around 5-10ms per frame(1280x720) on a GTX 660 (observed to be 10 times faster than CPU implementation). But tracing the line segments from the min, max points takes 1ms-15ms.

I have two questions on line detection

1. Does there exist a better algorithm to get the line segments from the min, max points of the hough bins?
2. Is it possible to optimize hought_line_transform (see the code below) further? I am using atomic operations. Is it possible to avoid atomics.

I am attaching the code below.

class Header

```
#ifndef _HOUGH_LINES_H_
#define _HOUGH_LINES_H_

#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

union Pos;
struct Line;

struct Hough_params
{
    int w;
    int h;
    int r;
};

class Hough_lines
{
public:
    enum Type {INT, SHORT_INT, FLOAT};

    Hough_lines(int _w, int _h);
    ~Hough_lines();

public:
    bool init();
    bool detect_lines(GLuint tex_edge, int threshold, int min_length, int min_gap, GLuint line, Type type, int& count);

protected:
    void get_edges(thrust::device_vector<Pos>& d_coords, int& size);
    void get_hough_lines(int threshold, thrust::device_vector<Line>& d_lines, int& size);
    void get_lines(int threshold, int min_length, int min_gap, GLuint line, Hough_lines::Type type, int& count);
    void trace_all_lines(int min_len, int min_gap, thrust::device_vector<Line>& d_lines, int size, int* d_line_coord, int& count);

    static void compute_trig_funcs();

protected:
    Hough_params params;
    thrust::device_vector<Hough_params> d_param;

    static bool trig_init;
};

#endif
```

Body

```
#include <hough_lines.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>

#include <cuda_gl_interop.h>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>

#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>

#define ANGLE_SIZE 360
#define MAX_LINE_PER_THREAD 10

union Pos
{
    struct
    {
        uint16_t x;
        uint16_t y;
    };
    uint32_t value;
};

struct Hough_info
{
    Pos end;
    Pos start;
    int count;
};

struct Line
{
    Pos start;
    Pos end;
};

struct Line_info
{
    int line_count;
    Line line[MAX_LINE_PER_THREAD];
};

__constant__ float dev_sint[ANGLE_SIZE];
__constant__ float dev_cost[ANGLE_SIZE];

texture<uint8_t, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> luma_tex;

bool Hough_lines::trig_init = false;

__global__ void mark_edges(const Hough_params* param, int* edge)
{
    int x = (blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x);
    int y = (blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y);
    int pos = x+(param->w*y);   
    edge[pos] = (255 == tex2D(luma_tex, x, y))?1:0;
}

__global__ void get_coords(const Hough_params* param, int* edge, Pos* coord)
{
    int index;
    int x = (blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x);
    int y = (blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y);
    int pos = x+(param->w*y);   
    if (255 == tex2D(luma_tex, x, y))
    {
        index = edge[pos];
        coord[index].y = y;
        coord[index].x = x;
    }
}

__global__ void hough_line_transform(const Hough_params* param, int size, const Pos* coord, int threshold, int *mark, Hough_info* out)
{
    int i;
    int angle;
    int rdata;
    __shared__ Hough_info sh_rho_data[1001];

    i = threadIdx.x;
    while (i < param->r)
    {
        sh_rho_data[i].end.value = 0x0;
        sh_rho_data[i].start.value = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        sh_rho_data[i].count = 0;

        i += blockDim.x;
    }
    __syncthreads();

    i = threadIdx.x;
    angle = blockIdx.x;
    const float cos_angle = dev_cost[angle];
    const float sin_angle = dev_sint[angle];
    while (i < size)
    {
        rdata = (int)ceil(((float)(coord[i].x-(param->w>>1))*cos_angle)+((float)((param->h>>1)-coord[i].y)*sin_angle));
        if (rdata >= 0)
        {
            atomicMax(&sh_rho_data[rdata].end.value, coord[i].value);
            atomicMin(&sh_rho_data[rdata].start.value, coord[i].value);

            atomicAdd(&sh_rho_data[rdata].count, 1);
        }
        i += blockDim.x;
    }

    __syncthreads();

    i = threadIdx.x;
    rdata = (angle*param->r);
    while (i < param->r)
    {
        memcpy(&out[rdata+i], &sh_rho_data[i], sizeof(Hough_info));
        mark[rdata+i] = (sh_rho_data[i].count >= threshold)?1:0;
        i += blockDim.x;
    }
}

__global__ void get_lines(const Hough_params* param, int threshold, Hough_info* hdata, int* mark, Line* lines)
{
    int pos;
    int i = threadIdx.x;
    int offset = (blockIdx.x*param->r);
    while (i < param->r)
    {
        if (hdata[offset+i].count >= threshold)
        {
            pos = mark[offset+i];
            lines[pos].start.value = hdata[offset+i].start.value;
            lines[pos].end.value = hdata[offset+i].end.value;
        }
        i += blockDim.x;
    }
}

__device__ void add_line(int xs, int ys, int xe, int ye, int min_len, Line_info* line)
{
    int d = abs(xe-xs)+abs(ye-ys);
    if ((d >= min_len) && (line->line_count < MAX_LINE_PER_THREAD))
    {
        line->line[line->line_count].start.x = xs;
        line->line[line->line_count].start.y = ys;
        line->line[line->line_count].end.x = xe;
        line->line[line->line_count].end.y = ye;

        ++line->line_count;

        //printf("\n(%d %d) (%d %d) %d", xs, ys, xe, ye, d);
    }
} 

__global__ void trace_lines(const Line* input, int inp_size, int min_len, int min_gap, Line_info* line_info, int* mark)
{
    int d;
    int dsub;
    int dstep;
    int xstep;
    int ystep;

    int xs, ys, xe, ye;
    int i = (blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x);
    if (i >= inp_size)
    {
        return;
    }

    xs = input[i].start.x;
    ys = input[i].start.y;
    xe = input[i].end.x;
    ye = input[i].end.y;

    line_info[i].line_count = 0;

    int dx = abs(xe-xs);
    int dy = abs(ye-ys);
    int xinc = (xe > xs)?1:-1;
    int yinc = (ye > ys)?1:-1;

    int gap = 0;
    bool sflag;
    int s_x, s_y, e_x, e_y;

    if (dx > dy)
    {
        dsub = (dx<<1);
        dstep = (dy<<1);
        d = dstep-dx;
        xstep = xinc;
        ystep = 0;
        xinc = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        dsub = (dy<<1);
        dstep = (dx<<1);
        d = dstep-dy;
        xstep = 0;
        ystep = yinc;
        yinc = 0;
    }

    sflag = true;
    s_x = xs;
    s_y = ys;
    e_x = xs;
    e_y = ys;

    int x = xs;
    int y = ys;

    while ((abs(x-xs) <= dx) && (abs(y-ys) <= dy))
    {
        x += xstep;
        y += ystep;
        if (d > 0)
        {
            x += xinc;
            y += yinc;

            d -= dsub;
        }
        d += dstep;

        if (255 == tex2D(luma_tex, x, y))
        {
            e_x = x;
            e_y = y;
            gap = 0;

            if (!sflag)
            {
                s_x = x;
                s_y = y;
                sflag = true;
            }
        }
        else if (sflag)
        {
            ++gap;
            if (gap >= min_gap)
            {
                sflag = false;
                add_line(s_x, s_y, e_x, e_y, min_len, &line_info[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    if (sflag)
    {
        add_line(s_x, s_y, xe, ye, min_len, &line_info[i]);
    }
    mark[i] = line_info[i].line_count;
}

__global__ void copy_line_coords(const Hough_params* param, Line_info* line, int size, int* mark, int* coords, int* count)
{
    int index = (blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x);
    if (index >= size)
    {
        return;
    }

    int pos;
    int start = 4*mark[index];
    Line* line_data = &line[index].line[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < line[index].line_count; i++)
    {
        pos = start+(4*i);
        coords[pos] = line_data[i].start.x-(param->w>>1);
        coords[pos+1] = (param->h>>1)-line_data[i].start.y;
        coords[pos+2] = line_data[i].end.x-(param->w>>1);
        coords[pos+3] = (param->h>>1)-line_data[i].end.y;
    }

    if ((index+1) == size)
    {
        *count = mark[index];
    }
}

Hough_lines::Hough_lines(int _w, int _h)
    :d_param(1)
{
    params.w = _w;
    params.h = _h;
    params.r = (int)ceil(0.5*sqrt((_w*_w)+(_h*_h)));
    thrust::copy_n(&params, 1, d_param.begin());
}

Hough_lines::~Hough_lines()
{
}

bool Hough_lines::init()
{
    if (false == trig_init)
    {
        trig_init = true;
        compute_trig_funcs();
    }
    return true;
}

void Hough_lines::compute_trig_funcs()
{
    float theta;
    cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;
    static float sint[ANGLE_SIZE];
    static float cost[ANGLE_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < ANGLE_SIZE; i++)
    {
        theta = (M_PI*(float)i)/180.0;
        sint[i] = sin(theta);
        cost[i] = cos(theta);
    }

    err = cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_sint, sint, ANGLE_SIZE*sizeof(float));
    err = (cudaSuccess == err) ? cudaMemcpyToSymbol(dev_cost, cost, ANGLE_SIZE*sizeof(float)):err;
    if (cudaSuccess != err)
    {
        printf("\n%s", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
    } 
}

void Hough_lines::get_edges(thrust::device_vector<Pos>& d_coords, int& size)
{
    dim3 bsize(16, 16);
    dim3 gsize(params.w/bsize.x, params.h/bsize.y);
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_mark(params.w*params.h);

    size = 0;
    mark_edges<<<gsize, bsize>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_param.data()),
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_mark.data()));
    thrust::exclusive_scan(d_mark.begin(), d_mark.end(), d_mark.begin());
    get_coords<<<gsize, bsize>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_param.data()),
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_mark.data()),
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_coords.data()));
    thrust::copy_n(d_mark.begin()+d_mark.size()-1, 1, &size);
}

void Hough_lines::get_hough_lines(int threshold, thrust::device_vector<Line>& d_lines, int& size)
{
    int edge_count = 0;
    thrust::device_vector<Pos> d_coords(params.w*params.h); 
    get_edges(d_coords, edge_count);

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_mark(params.r*360);
    thrust::device_vector<Hough_info> d_hough_data(params.r*360);
    hough_line_transform<<<360, 256>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_param.data()),
        edge_count,
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_coords.data()), threshold,
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_mark.data()), 
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_hough_data.data())); 
    thrust::exclusive_scan(d_mark.begin(), d_mark.end(), d_mark.begin());
    ::get_lines<<<360, 256>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_param.data()),
        threshold,
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_hough_data.data()),
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_mark.data()),
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_lines.data()));
    thrust::copy_n(d_mark.begin()+d_mark.size()-1, 1, &size);
}

void Hough_lines::trace_all_lines(int min_len, int min_gap, thrust::device_vector<Line>& d_lines, int size, int* d_line_coord, int& count)
{
    thrust::device_vector<int> d_mark_line(size);
    thrust::device_vector<Line_info> d_nlines(size);

    trace_lines<<<(1+(size/512)), 512>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_lines.data()), 
        size, min_len, min_gap, thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_nlines.data()),
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_mark_line.data()));

    thrust::exclusive_scan(d_mark_line.begin(), d_mark_line.end(), d_mark_line.begin());

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_count(1);
    copy_line_coords<<<(1+(size/512)), 512>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_param.data()),
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_nlines.data()), size,
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_mark_line.data()), d_line_coord,
        thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_count.data()));

    thrust::copy(d_count.begin(), d_count.end(), &count);
    //printf("\nLine count: %d", count);
}

void Hough_lines::get_lines(int threshold, int min_len, int min_gap, GLuint line, Hough_lines::Type type, int& count)
{
    int* d_line_coord = 0;
    cudaGLRegisterBufferObject(line);
    cudaGLMapBufferObject((void **)&d_line_coord, line);

    int size = 0;
    thrust::device_vector<Line> d_lines(params.r*360); 
    get_hough_lines(threshold, d_lines, size);
    //printf("\nget_hough_lines: %d", size);

    trace_all_lines(min_len, min_gap, d_lines, size, d_line_coord, count);

    cudaGLUnmapBufferObject(line);
    cudaGLUnregisterBufferObject(line);
    }

    bool Hough_lines::detect_lines(GLuint tex_edge, int threshold, int min_length, int min_gap, GLuint line, Hough_lines::Type type, int& count)
    {
    cudaError_t err;
    cudaArray* array_edge;
    cudaGraphicsResource* res_edge;

    err = cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage(&res_edge, tex_edge, GL_TEXTURE_2D, cudaGraphicsRegisterFlagsReadOnly);
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage Failed: %s", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
        exit(0);
    }

    cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &res_edge);
    cudaChannelFormatDesc chan_desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<uint8_t>();
    err = cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray(&array_edge, res_edge, 0, 0);
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("cudaGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray Failed: %s", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
        exit(0);
    }

    if (cudaBindTextureToArray(&luma_tex, array_edge, &chan_desc) != cudaSuccess)
    {
        printf("Failed to bind texture - %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
        exit(0);
    }

    float time = 0.0;
    //static float max = 0.0;
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;

    cudaEventCreate(&start);
    cudaEventCreate(&stop);
    cudaEventRecord(start);

    count = 0;
    get_lines(threshold, min_length, min_gap, line, type, count);

    cudaEventRecord(stop);
    cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
    cudaEventElapsedTime(&time, start, stop);

    //static int frame = 0;
    //frame++;
    //if (time > max)
    {
        //max = time;
        printf("\nElpased time: %f ms", time);
    }

    cudaEventDestroy(start);
    cudaEventDestroy(stop);

    cudaUnbindTexture(luma_tex);   
    cudaGraphicsUnmapResources(1, &res_edge);
    cudaGraphicsUnregisterResource(res_edge);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: I think this type of "optimize my whole program" question is a bit broad for the SO format.  If you can narrow it down and post a more targeted question, you'll get better help.

Comment: Re-factored the question to make it more specific.

Comment: In ["Prefix sums and their applications"](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/papers/Ble93.pdf), Guy Blelloch described a parallel line-drawing algorithm using parallel prefix sum. See page 55 of that paper -- does that help?  BTW, shared memory atomics are quite slow. Also, you call "memcpy" inside your kernel inside a while loop.  EVERY thread is doing that memcpy, which is a lot of duplication -- that is slow and redundant.  BTW, I  still think your question is too broad for the SO format.

Comment: @harrism maybe you should post this last comment as an answer. It seems to me like you've pointed to a better way to do it. I think it contributes something useful and would upvote it.

Comment: @harrism, thanks for the link to parallel line-drawing algorithm. I believe it is really helpful. Regarding memcpy I am copying the results from shared memory to global memory. Each thread produces an output which needs to be copied.

Answer (score 2):

In ["Prefix sums and their applications"](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guyb/papers/Ble93.pdf), Guy Blelloch described a parallel line-drawing algorithm using parallel prefix sum. See page 55 of that paper, it might give you ideas.

Regarding how to optimize `hough_line_transfer`, I think the key is to eliminate shared memory atomics in your loop. Where you use them you are effectively doing keyed reductions. Thrust provides a `reduce_by_key` function, but that is only callable from the host. The device-library counterpart to Thrust is CUB, but it does not have `reduce_by_key`. I've asked the CUB authors for ideas here and if we come up with anything I'll update this answer.

You could write your own keyed reduction but it would be more productive and robust to rely on a library if possible.